# DocuSign embedded signing, create envelope from pdf, recipients, UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on your demo environment using your REST API.  My goal is to take a PDF, create an envelope for embedded signing, get the embedded signing URL back, have the user navigate to that page, sign the document, and have a recipient receive a copy of the finished signed document.

I've had some success, but I can't seem to get clientUserId to work correctly in the recipients/signers section when the signer does not exist as a recipient.  I believe clientUserId is supposed to allow this to happen.

If I exactly match the 'signers' with an existing recipient, it works fine (for example, using myself as a recipient).

Here's my request to POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/517564/envelopes:

```
 {
   "emailBlurb" : "This comes from....",
   "accountId" : "123456",
   "emailSubject" : "Please Sign This....",
   "documents" : [
      {
         "documentId" : "1",
         "name" : "the_document.pdf"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "sent",
   "recipients" : {
      "signers" : [
         {
            "tabs" : {
               "carbonCopies" : [
                  {
                     "email" : "real-email@soemwhere.com",
                     "name" : "The Signer",
                     "recipientId" : "2",
                     "routingOrder" : "2"
                  }
               ],
               "signHereTabs" : [
                  {
                     "documentId" : "1",
                     "xPosition" : "50",
                     "pageNumber" : "1",
                     "yPosition" : "160"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "email" : "internetuser1@email.com",
            "name" : "John Public",
            "clientUserId" : "991003",
            "recipientId" : "1",
            "routingOrder" : "1"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This will return UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT as John Public is not a recipient in the Docusign system.  But I do have clientUserId set to 991003, which I believe your walkthroughs says is a sufficient element/tag to allow this through.

I've tried several combinations of things and following the blurbs in your walkthroughs.

Does anyone have any insight.

Answer (score 0):

**This should work for you:**

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "accountId": "378713",
    "emailBlurb": "This comes from....",
    "emailSubject": "Please Sign This....",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "the_document.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "internetuser1@email.com",
                "name": "John Public",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "clientUserId": "991003",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "xPosition": "50",
                            "yPosition": "160",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "carbonCopies": [
                        {
                            "email": "recipient@mymail.com",
                            "name": "Mr My Final Reviewer",
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "routingOrder": "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like I made some mistakes when I was redacting out data when I posted the question.  I copied and pasted your snip of JSON in, but little improvement.  It now complains with:

The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope. Envelope recipient could not be determined. \'clientUserId\', \'email\', or \'userName\' in request and envelope may not match.

I left my demo account id in the message with myself as the recipient.   It's still not matching for some reason.

Comment: Even removing the carbonCopies element, it still gives: 


{
          'errorCode' => 'UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT',
          'message' => 'The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope. Envelope recipient could not be determined. \'clientUserId\', \'email\', or \'userName\' in request and envelope may not match.'
        };

Comment: Interesting, I am not getting that error. You did change the account ID from my response, correct?

Comment: Yes, I did.  I'm starting to wonder if it's the case that some other subtle problem with transport, or encoding, or something else with my request sending...and it's just dumping this error message as a default.

I used the iodocs rest api "TRY IT" tool... and I get back a good response.

I'll re-examine everything in my chain and advise.

Comment: I did finally make it through with success. I've made several changes at once, will update/answer question when I find the exact culprit. Thanks for checking on things with me so far.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem. It looks like I had a couple problems:

1. My transcoding to JSON was wrong and was dumping out the @ in the email address field.
2. I had an extra carriage return in the multi-part form data boundary separator.

Thanks to [Justin M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821709/justin-m) for looking into things for me!